# Parsec and Applicative style

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, applicative

can someone help me to understand how to use Applicative style for writing Parsec parsers? This is the code i have:

```
module Main where
import Control.Applicative hiding (many)
import Text.Parsec
import Data.Functor.Identity
data Cmd = A | B deriving (Show)

main = do
  line <- getContents
  putStrLn . show $ parseCmd line

parseCmd :: String -> Either ParseError String
parseCmd input =  parse cmdParse "(parser)" input

cmdParse :: Parsec String () String
cmdParse = do
  slash <- char '/'
  whatever <- many alphaNum
  return (slash:whatever)

cmdParse2 :: String -> Parsec String () String
cmdParse2 = (:) <$> (char '/') <*> many alphaNum
```

but when i try to compile it, i get following:

```
/home/tomasherman/Desktop/funinthesun.hs:21:13:
    Couldn't match expected type `Parsec String () String'
                with actual type `[a0]'
    Expected type: a0 -> [a0] -> Parsec String () String
      Actual type: a0 -> [a0] -> [a0]
    In the first argument of `(<$>)', namely `(:)'
    In the first argument of `(<*>)', namely `(:) <$> (char '/')'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

The idea is that i want cmdParse2 to do same thing that cmdParse does, but using applicative stuff...my approach is probably completely wrong, i'm new to haskell

Comment: Your error is as if you had written `(++) <$> ...` not `(:) <$> ...`.

Comment: sorry, fixed .. i was trying it with both ++ and : and got it mixed up

Comment: The ultimate in well-researched questions, because the answer is "Well done, sound choice, done correctly, but fix this minor type error." +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your applicative usage is spot on, you just have an incorrect signature. Try:

```
cmdParse2 :: Parsec String () String
```

Comment: just a quick question, is it possible to get type Text from 'many alphaNum'? so i don't always pack it manually if i want to use Text instead of String?

Comment: @Arg 1. Yes. You could convert: `(pack <$> many alphaNum)`, but you'll need to convert everything: `cmdParse3 = cons <$> char '/' <*> (pack <$> many alphaNum)` but that's better written `cmdParse4 = pack <$> cmdParse2`, and it might be better, depending on your application to leave it till the end and do `pack <$> myTopLevelParser`. (You might be interested in `Text.Parsec.Text` to change the source data too.) 2. Why? You're building up strings a character at a time, combining them the good way. `append` is _O(n)_ for Text anyway.

Comment: ok, thanks for the tip. Btw, so awesome that haskell has function complexities for it's operations in documentation

Answer (score 4):

Your approach looks correct to me, the problem is that `cmdParse2` has the wrong type. It should have the same type as `cmdParse`. By the way, you can omit the parens around `char '/'` in the applicative style parser.